# Replace Apostrophe with double Apostrophe

Tags: sql-server-2008, replace, apostrophe

I've recently been asked to look into SQL for the first time and have come across an issue which i cant figure out and was hoping to seek help, i have two SQL servers both running Microsoft SQL Server 2008 and Server A has a linked server to Server B,

a trigger exists which sends data into a stored procedure which then passes the data on insert from server A to server B and this data has names in, the problem i am facing is that names like O'Neil are failing due to the apostrophe and i cant figure out how to replace the apostrophe with double apostrophe's when the data im harvesting is only available from the 'inserted' table.

my trigger is as follows:

```
 SELECT @PassengerName=PassengerName, @DocumentType=DocumentType, @BoardingSequenceNumber=BoardingSequenceNumber,
        @FlightNumber=FlightNumber, @CarrierCode=CarrierCode, @DepartureTime=DepartureTime, @Destination=Destination, @DeviceAddress=DeviceAddress, 
        @Timestamp="Timestamp", @WorkstationId=WorkstationId, @DeliveredTimeStamp=DeliveredTimeStamp from inserted;

SELECT @cmd = 'sqlcmd -S '+@@SERVERNAME+' -E -d '+DB_NAME()+' -Q "exec SP_transfer @PassengerName='''+@PassengerName+''',@DocumentType='+@DocumentType+
',@BoardingSequenceNumber='+cast(@BoardingSequenceNumber as varchar(20))+
',@FlightNumber='+@FlightNumber+',@CarrierCode='+@CarrierCode+
',@DepartureTime='''+cast(@DepartureTime as varchar(20))+''',@Destination='+@Destination+
',@DeviceAddress='+@DeviceAddress+''',@TimeStamp='+cast(@Timestamp as varchar(32))+
''',@WorkstationId='+@WorkstationId+',@DeliveredTimeStamp='''+cast(@DeliveredTimeStamp as varchar(50))+'''"';
```

how can i make it so that the passengername column replaces any apostrophes without breaking the trigger but before it attempts to fire? i appologies if this question seems stupid, but as i mentioned im pretty new to this line of work,

thank you for your time,

Craig

Comment: Look into using the stored proc [`SP_ExecuteSQL`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) directly passing the parameters, rather than trying to escape the values yourself and mash them into a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure if you want to remove or replace the apostrophes in the select. There is a replace function in SQL  replace(string, replacestring, replacewith)

```
SELECT  replace('test','est', 'aste')
returns 
Taste
```

So depending on the fields you are using you can strip out the apostrophes on the select of the trigger.

```
SELECT  
    @PassengerName=replace(PassengerName,'''',''),
    @DocumentType=replace(DocumentType,'''',''),
    @BoardingSequenceNumber=replace(BoardingSequenceNumber,'''',''),
    @FlightNumber=replace(FlightNumber,'''',''),
    @CarrierCode=replace(CarrierCode,'''',''),
    @DepartureTime=replace(DepartureTime,'''',''),
    @Destination=replace(Destination,'''',''),
    @DeviceAddress=replace(DeviceAddress,'''',''),
    @Timestamp="Timestamp",
    @WorkstationId=WorkstationId,
    @DeliveredTimeStamp=DeliveredTimeStamp 
from inserted;
```

If you don't want to remote the apostrophes you could double them up in the same way.

Comment: i was looking at the replace function but couldnt work out how the sytax would work when i was using the declared names... you've just made this look so simple i feel like a fool for missing it! :D thank you very much i'll give this a go ! :)

Comment: if i wanted to double them up would i do the order reversed? ie @PassengerName=replace(passengername,'','''') ? thanks

Comment: This should hopefully give you an idea; its not the most elegant but balances it out SELECT  replace('o''neil','''', '''''')

Comment: sorry i think im missunderstanding this ... if i wanted to make sure the name O'Neil or any other name with O' at the start got passed from Table one to table two would i use SELECT REPLACE(PassengerName,'''','''''') ? sorry about the confusion

Comment: ok sorry i've reread all of this with a clear head and understand now, and i've tested what you say and it works so thank you very much :)